# rsync: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: bash, rsync

I get this despite that remindfox.ics is copied.

Any fix?

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/dsgt0f2o.default/reminderfox.ics" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]


#!/bin/bash 

Seamonkey_Dir="/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/dsgt0f2o.default/"
Backup_Directory="/media/storagedrive/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/"
Seamonkey_Reminder_Dir="/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/dsgt0f2o.default/reminderfox/"

UbuntuMate_20_04_ReminderFox_Dir="/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/7g4136n1.default/reminderfox/"

# Backup reminderfox reminders This WORKS
cd $Seamonkey_Dir
rsync --progress -r -u -q reminderfox.ics $Backup_Directory 
#
# Copy reminderfox .ics file to the 20.04 installation
# This WORKS despite any rsync errors.
# 
rsync --progress -r -u -q $Seamonkey_Reminder_Dir/reminderfox.ics $UbuntuMate_20_04_ReminderFox_Dir
```

Comment: Not exactly sure, but try remove the trailing `/` from your `Seamonkey_Reminder_Dir` variable. Currently, you are introducing a double slash.

Comment: How do you see I am introducing a double slash? I removed the trailing slash. No change. @JG7

Comment: Your variable contains the reminderfox directory where your error does not. Previous comment states the double //. Once in your variable and again in your Rsync command